# NOT IN sub-query returning no results

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I am trying to get a list of instructors who have never taught a course section.

I first select and I get bunch of results who taught a course

```
SELECT w.COURSE_NO,z.SALUTATION, z.FIRST_NAME, z.LAST_NAME,z.ZIP
FROM INSTRUCTOR z , SECTION w
WHERE z.INSTRUCTOR_ID = w.INSTRUCTOR_ID;
```

but when I do NOT IN so that I can see what instructor never taught a course section it gives me no rows.

```
SELECT a.SALUTATION, a.FIRST_NAME, a.LAST_NAME,a.ZIP
FROM INSTRUCTOR a,SECTION b 
WHERE a.INSTRUCTOR_ID = b.INSTRUCTOR_ID AND b.COURSE_NO NOT IN
(SELECT w.COURSE_NO
FROM INSTRUCTOR z , SECTION w
WHERE z.INSTRUCTOR_ID = w.INSTRUCTOR_ID)
ORDER BY a.SALUTATION, a.FIRST_NAME, a.LAST_NAME,a.ZIP;
```

why is it giving me no rows when I am trying to select those who never a course section ?

Comment: Check about `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: It's giving you 0 rows because your sub-query and your main-query have the same conditions and join, which means that they return the same results. Your query becomes `select * from a where id not in ( select id from a)`. Your query is incorrect. Can you post sample data (both raw and expected results).

Comment: It should be `WHERE INSTRUCTOR NOT IN (SELECT INSTRUCTOR ...)`, with the subquery returning the list of instructors who have taught a section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are getting only rows that are in `SECTION`.  It seems like you want:

```
SELECT a.SALUTATION, a.FIRST_NAME, a.LAST_NAME,a.ZIP
FROM INSTRUCTOR a 
WHERE a.INSTRUCTOR_ID NOT IN
(SELECT w.INSTRUCTOR_ID 
FROM SECTION w)
ORDER BY a.SALUTATION, a.FIRST_NAME, a.LAST_NAME,a.ZIP;
```

Or

```
SELECT a.SALUTATION, a.FIRST_NAME, a.LAST_NAME,a.ZIP
FROM INSTRUCTOR a 
LEFT JOIN SECTION w ON a.INSTRUCTOR_ID = w.INSTRUCTOR_ID
WHERE w.INSTRUCTOR_ID IS NULL
ORDER BY a.SALUTATION, a.FIRST_NAME, a.LAST_NAME,a.ZIP;
```

Comment: I was going for course number instead of instructor :(...I just went full retard..Thank you!